# dev-cpp\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status What error is the compiler pointing out?

Tags: c, data-structures

I am using **dev c++** for practicing data structures in C. After compiling any program, it runs for the first time.In subsequent runs,

the compiler shows following error: 
     `dev-cpp\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status`

What error is the compiler pointing out??

Comment: Are you sure the first program has stopped running? Is it possible your antivirus is interfering?

Answer (score 0):

There's unfortunately not much information to go on. One thing that's always helped me so much, when troubleshooting mysterious GNU LD errors, is using the `--cref -Map=$@.map` flags (where $@ is the name of the output file). It'll save a report explaining every single decision the linker makes, in painstaking detail.